# Regex remove repeated characters from a string by javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have found a way to remove repeated characters from a string using regular expressions.

```
function RemoveDuplicates() {
    var str = "aaabbbccc";
    var filtered = str.replace(/[^\w\s]|(.)\1/gi, "");  
    alert(filtered);
}
```

Output: `abc`
this is working fine.

But if `str = "aaabbbccccabbbbcccccc"` then output is `abcabc`.
Is there any way to get only unique characters or remove all duplicates one?
Please let me know if there is any way.

Comment: Does the order matter? In other words, is it necessary that the first occurrence of the character is the one you save?

Comment: i want characters in same sequence after remove duplicates one. Only unique one.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

A lookahead like "this, followed by something and this":

```js
var str = "aaabbbccccabbbbcccccc";
console.log(str.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "")); // "abc"
```

Note that this preserves the *last* occurrence of each character:

```js
var str = "aabbccxccbbaa";
console.log(str.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "")); // "xcba"
```

Without regexes, preserving order:

```js
var str = "aabbccxccbbaa";
console.log(str.split("").filter(function(x, n, s) {
  return s.indexOf(x) == n
}).join("")); // "abcx"
```

Comment: I asked Mike but he has not answered yet. Your solution is the one I would have gone with, and if you need to preserve order, wouldn't `str.split("").reverse().join("")` do the trick?

Comment: by running this code... string is not coming in same seqeunce. if var str = "aaabbbcccaabbbcccaaaaaaaasa"; output = "bcsa" but i want something like abcs

Comment: @Lindrian: yes, that, or some other method from http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Comment: How would you preserve the first occurance?

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question, but in ES6 we can use [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). The code looks like this:

```js
var test = 'aaabbbcccaabbbcccaaaaaaaasa';
var result = Array.from(new Set(test)).join('');

console.log(result);
```