# How do you remove repetitions in string characters,and sort it?

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with this, it is supposed to take 2 string and return the largest one, sorted alphabetically, with no repetitions.

like `String x = "xbbacd"` and `String y = "ppacd"` 
would return "abcdx".

It's also giving a no output return without System.....ln();

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MyClass {
    public static String longest(String s1, String s2) {
        // your code

        HashSet<String> list1 = new HashSet<String>();
        HashSet<String> list2 = new HashSet<String>();

        for (char x : s1.toCharArray()) {
            String y = Character.toString(x);
            list1.add(y);
        }

        for (char q : s2.toCharArray()) {
            String y = Character.toString(q);
            list2.add(y);
        }

        ArrayList<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String t : list1) {
            arr1.add(t);
        }
        for (String z : list2) {
            arr2.add(z);
        }

        Collections.sort(arr1);
        Collections.sort(arr2);

        String one = "";

        if (arr1.size() > arr2.size()) {
            for (String i : arr1) {
                one = one + i;
            }
        } else {
            for (String i : arr2) {
                one = one + i;
            }
        }

        // System.out.print(one);

        return one;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeleteMe a = new DeleteMe();
        a.longest("adfafasf", "xvsdvwv");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex remove repeated characters from a string by javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301806/regex-remove-repeated-characters-from-a-string-by-javascript) , no matter if javascript or java...is just regex

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ This is likely a high school student just learning to code and he/she probably hasn't been exposed to regex yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the string length in the beginning you do not need to process both strings, just the longer one. You save quite a bit of coding effort by only working on the longer string. You should also check on how to handle the edge cases of both strings being equal in length, null, empty strings, etc.

Try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MyClass {

    public static String longest (String s1, String s2) {
    // your code
    if (len1 == null) return "String 1 is null";
    if (len2 == null) return "String 2 is null";

    // first determine which string is longer
    int len1 = s1.length();
    int len2 = s2.length();
    String longerString = null;
    if (len1 >= len2) {
        longerString = len1;
    } else {
        longerString = len2;
    }
    HashSet<String> stringHash = new HashSet<String>();

    for(char x : longerString.toCharArray() )
    {
        String y = Character.toString(x);
        stringHash.add(y);
    }

    ArrayList<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();

   for(String t : list1){    arr1.add(t);    }
   Collections.sort(arr1);

   String one = new String();
   for(String i : arr1){       one = one + i;     }

   // System.out.print(one);

   return one;

}

public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    MyClass a = new MyClass();
    System.out.println(a.longest("adfafasf","xvsdvwv"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could (and most likely should) extract the 'distinct and sort' part of your method into a new method to reduce code-duplication. Your variable names are somewhat confusing (at least for me) as you name a set 'list' and a list 'arr'.
Regarding the no output: You currently do not use the return value of the method, you want your last line to be `System.out.println(longest("adfafasf", "xvsdvwv");`

Below a refactored version of your version (the creation of the shorter string could be avoided but performance seems negligible for this problem):

```
public static String longest(
        final String s1,
        final String s2) {
    ////
    final String ds1 = distinctSorted(s1);
    final String ds2 = distinctSorted(s2);
    return ds1.length() >= ds2.length() ? ds1 : ds2;
}

private static String distinctSorted(
        final String s) {
    ////
    final Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (final char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        set.add(c);
    }

    final List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
    Collections.sort(list);

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(list.size());
    for (final char c : list) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

An alternative for the distinct and sort method:

```
private static String distinctSorted(
        final String s) {
    ////
    return s.chars().sorted().distinct()
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
}
```