# All characters occur just once with javascript replace function

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I couldn't do the same in javascript that I could in php.

for example :

```
$old_v = "aaaggggoooaooogg";
echo preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", $old_v);
```

the result is: "ago"

.... so every character just occurs once after using preg_replace. I'd like to do the same in javascript ... but I couldn't.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301806/regex-remove-repeated-characters-from-a-string-by-javascript (your php version uses replace here in js a regex has been used)

Comment: Actually, in PHP, your code will yield [`agoaog`](https://ideone.com/g4gpQw)

Comment: Both of you were right ... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please:

```
var x = "aaaggggoooaooogg"; 
y= x.split("");
var unique = myArray.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i); 
var z = unique.join("");
```

Or with regexp:

```
var x = "aaaggggoooaooogg"; 
x.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "")
```

Comment: You should explain _why_ he should try this and also explain what it does. Just post a "random" piece of code isn't all that helpful.

Comment: The second one (with regex) returns: `aog`