# How to convert string "aabbccddaaacccddddbbbc" in to "abcdacdbc". It should only take first letter in a sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this and got it. But can a better solution be obtained by using Regex?

```
var str = "aabbccddaaacccddddbbbc";
var strA = str.split('');    
strA.forEach(function(ele) {
    if(temp !== ele){
        console.log(ele);
    }
    temp = ele;
});
// abcdacdbc
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex remove repeated characters from a string by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301806/regex-remove-repeated-characters-from-a-string-by-javascript)

Comment: I was just thinking about how the -5 markdown on the OP seemed excessive, and the people doing that ought to explain why in comments. It would be nice in the future if you could phrase your question more generally, so there is better chance to add to general knowledge (or find an existing answer in your search). The link Mike posted above is a good example of generalizing your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replacing by regex to achieve this:

```js
const result = 'aabbccddaaacccddddbbbc'.replace(/(\w)\1*/g, '$1');

document.write(result);
```