# Remove certain re-occurring characters from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am quite new to JS and i have a problem:

I am trying to compare a string (as integer) with an input (as integer). The problem occurs because, the string is written as 10'000'000 for e.g. and the integer as 10000000, with 4 possible scenarios: 
- 1'000'000 
- 10'000'000 
- 100'000'000 
- 1'000'000'000

That is, the number (as string) can be from 1 million to 1 billion.

I want to erase (or replace with "") all of my " ' " characters so that the format which i will get for the string will be the same as the one of the integer

E.g. Integer: 95500000 String: 95'500'000 ---> need it to be 95500000

A similar solution but not quite the same is provided here:
[Regex remove repeated characters from a string by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301806/regex-remove-repeated-characters-from-a-string-by-javascript)

Comment: You're not trying to remove "repeating" characters, or even "re-occurring" ones. You just want to remove anything that's not numeric.

Answer (score 2):

> String: 95'500'000 ---> need it to be 95500000

That’s as simple as `"95'500'000".replace(/'/g, '')`

`g` modifier makes it replace all occurrences, and not just the first one.

Comment: In addition to this, how to add " ' " to the integer (ofc. after using toString() on the integer or some other method) ?
I want to add " ' " to the stringified, starting from right to left, after every 3 digits.

Again, keep in mind i may have an integer with total of 7, 8, 9, 10 digits.

So for e.g. if i have 95500000, it should be  "  95'500'000 "

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = "9'0'0000"
const removedSlashStr = str.split('').reduce((removedSlash, char) => {
  if(char !== "'") removedSlash+=char
  return removedSlash
}, '')

console.log(removedSlashStr) // "900000"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.