# string to date object with arbitrary length format specification in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, type-conversion, date-parsing

I have several dates (strings) that I want to convert to date objects.

```js
const parse = (val, fmt) =>
{
    if (!val)
        return;
    const fn = (str, len) => val.substr(fmt.indexOf(str), len);

    return new Date(
        fn('YYYY', 4),
        fn('MM', 2) - 1,
        fn('DD', 2)
    );
};

console.log(parse('05/11/1896', 'DD/MM/YYYY')); // 1896-11-05
console.log(parse('07-12-2000', 'DD-MM-YYYY')); // 2000-12-07
console.log(parse('07:12:2000', 'DD:MM:YYYY')); // 2000-12-07
console.log(parse('2017/06/3', 'YYYY/MM/DD')); // 2017-06-03
console.log(parse('2017-06-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD')); // 2017-06-15
console.log(parse('2015 06 25', 'YYYY MM DD')); // 2015-06-25
```

However, I want to have a shorter format string, possibly as short as `mdy`. Can this be done?

I also want to support months or days without a leading zero; so `5/5/2021` instead of `05/05/2021`.

Thanks.

Comment: "*Can this be done?*" Yes, there are many parsers and formatters to chose from. Writing one isn't particularly difficult, though a little tedious. Do you have a coding question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with.

- It uses as regular expression to remove any characters from the format, then makes each character unique [using the method outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45323424/4710434).
- It then splits the input string based on another regex that finds the first non numerical character.
- It finally has the correct values to send to the Date object.

```js
const parse = (val, fmt) =>
{
    if (!val)
        return;
    fmt = Array.from(new Set(fmt.toLowerCase().replace(/[^dmy]/g, ''))).join('');
    const components = val.split(val.match(/[^0-9]/)[0]);
    let day = 1, month = 0, year, i = -1;
    while (i++ < 3)
        switch (fmt[i])
        {
            case 'd':
                day = components[i];
                break;
            case 'm':
                month = components[i] - 1;
                break;
            case 'y':
                year = components[i];
        }

    return new Date(year, month, day);
};

console.log(parse('05/11/1896', 'DD/MM/YYYY')); // 1896-11-05
console.log(parse('07-12-2000', 'DD-MM-YYYY')); // 2000-12-07
console.log(parse('07:12:2000', 'DD:MM:YYYY')); // 2000-12-07
console.log(parse('2017/6/3', 'YYYY/MM/DD')); // 2017-06-03
console.log(parse('2017-6-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD')); // 2017-06-15
console.log(parse('2015 6 25', 'YYYY MM DD')); // 2015-06-25
console.log(parse('2015 6 25', 'YyYy MM DD')); // 2015-06-25
console.log(parse('2015 6 25', 'Y-M-D')); // 2015-06-25
console.log(parse('2015 6 25', 'YYMD')); // 2015-06-25
```